# make a deb repository from packages installed in one server

Tags: apt, repository, deb, apt-mirror

i have to servers, the main of them , called server1 is a working ubuntu server, with some packages hold in some version, and some of them compiled from deb-src too.

I want to make a local repository with the packages installed in server1, to replicate over my network, then if i wanted to install postgresql (with my own changes, just as it is in server 1) in server2, i could get the package from my local repo compiled and versioned just in the exact way i installed in server1

Im thinkin / searching in some kind of script just after install one deb (from official repo, or local compiled) which will rsync to my local repo server. But i dont know if it is posible or there is another cleaner way to get it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a web server or some shared directory:

```
mkdir myrepo
copy all the .deb files to the myrepo folder
cd myrepo
dpkg-scanpackages ./ /dev/null |gzip > Packages.gz
```

then configure other machines to use that repo in /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb file:/home/your-user-name/myrepo/ ./
```

Also `apt-utils package` - contains the tool `apt-ftparchive` which is perfect for maintaining a reasonably sized internal repository

Comment: I will try, but i need to know how to download the packages installed (exact version) from the official repo to myrepo directorie, can you help me with that?

Comment: im reading about [aptitude-create-state-bundle](http://man.he.net/man1/aptitude-create-state-bundle) maybe it can help me